# Python Header missing, cannot compile cryptography

Tags: software-installation, python

Trying to install Airplay!  https://github.com/espes/Slave-in-the-Magic-Mirror

Set up virtualenv using http://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/

Installed python-dev: `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

Downloaded and extract latest version of pypy. Installed in virtual environment: `virtualenv -p pypy-4.0.1-linux64/bin/pypy env`

> `$ pypy -m pip install cryptography`

```
Collecting cryptography
  Using cached cryptography-1.2.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): idna>=2.0 in ./site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyasn1>=0.1.8 in ./site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.4.1 in ./site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools>=1.0 in ./site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): enum34 in ./site-packages (from cryptography)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipaddress in ./site-packages (from cryptography)
Building wheels for collected packages: cryptography
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cryptography
  Complete output from command /home/pershore/code/env/bin/pypy -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-XdGlez/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp0b4SnWpip-wheel-:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/__about__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/fernet.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
  copying src/cryptography/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/general_name.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/name.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
  copying src/cryptography/x509/oid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/interfaces.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/multibackend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/keywrap.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/binding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/_conditional.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/ciphers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/backend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x509.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ciphers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/x963kdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/pbkdf2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/hkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/concatkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/modes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/algorithms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/hotp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/totp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
  running egg_info
  writing src/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing entry points to src/cryptography.egg-info/entry_points.txt
  writing requirements to src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to src/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
  warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

  reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
  writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext
  generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_padding.c'
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_constant_time.c'
  generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c'
  building '_openssl' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  cc -O2 -fPIC -Wimplicit -I/home/pershore/code/env/include -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
  build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   #include <Python.h>
                      ^
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography
Installing collected packages: cryptography
  Running setup.py install for cryptography
    Complete output from command /home/pershore/code/env/bin/pypy -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-XdGlez/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-NXMx1t-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/pershore/code/env/include/site/python2.7/cryptography:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running egg_info
    writing src/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to src/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to src/cryptography.egg-info/entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to src/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
    writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_padding.c'
    already up-to-date
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_constant_time.c'
    already up-to-date
    generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c'
    already up-to-date
    building '_openssl' extension
    cc -O2 -fPIC -Wimplicit -I/home/pershore/code/env/include -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Python.h>
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/pershore/code/env/bin/pypy -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-XdGlez/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-NXMx1t-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/pershore/code/env/include/site/python2.7/cryptography" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-XdGlez/cryptography
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is probably not elementary OS specific. Try it over there at Stackoverflow.com

Comment: Possibly, but I'm only experiencing this in elementary.  All the other forums I have searched, the answer which is to install python-dev, fixes the problem.  But not on elementary.  I'll try on a regular ubuntu installation and **if** I have the same problem I agree this can be closed off.

Comment: same on ubuntu.  This can be closed, I'll try and get help elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the error message, right? Here are the steps to resolve similar case.

For first time only:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apt-file
$ apt-file update
```

Regular steps:

```
$ locate -r Python.h$
/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h

$ apt-file find /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h
libpython2.7-dev: /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h

$ sudo apt-get install libpython2.7-dev
```

Comment: Thankyou Sneetsher, but libpython2.7-dev was already installed.  I followed your steps though, and still get the error message that Python.h is missing - despite it clearly being there.

Comment: @MattB you need that header inside the virtual env, see `-I/home/pershore/code/env/include` in the output, try copy `cp -R /usr/include/python2.7/* /home/pershore/code/env/include/` . I'm not sure if you need v2.6 same as pypy version.